# How to put weather underground forecast icons

Tags: json, python-3.x, tkinter

i´m new to program with python and trying to put icons from weather underground forecast, but in line **labelimg1** don´t show any icon and dont give any error. Can anyone helpme.

I put here some part of the code.
Thanks in advance.

url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/xxxxxxxxx/forecast/q/PT/Lisbon.json"

```
    temp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    json_string = temp.read().decode('utf-8')
    parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
    high = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['high']['celsius']
    low = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['low']['celsius']
    con = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['conditions']
    day = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['date']['day']
    high1 = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][1]['high']['celsius']
    low1 = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][1]['low']['celsius']
    con1 = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][1]['conditions']
    day1 = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][1]['date']['day']
    **icon = parsed_json['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday'][0]['icon']**
    **img7 = PhotoImage(icon)**
    img8 = PhotoImage(file='c:/House/PNG/clear.png')
    **labelimg1 = Label(self, image=img7)**
    labelimg2 = Label(self, image=img8)
    label1 = Label(self, text="Dia: %s ,   Céu: %s" % (day, con,), font="Arial 12 bold")
    label2 = Label(self, text="Temperatura miníma de: %sº  - Temperatura máxima de: %sº " % (low, high,),
                   font="Arial 12 bold")
    label3 = Label(self, text="Dia: %s ,   Céu: %s " % (day1, con1,), font="Arial 12 bold")
    label4 = Label(self, text="Temperatura miníma de: %sº  - Temperatura máxima de: %sº " % (low1, high1,),
                   font="Arial 12 bold")
    label1.pack(pady=15)
    **labelimg1.image = img7
    labelimg1.pack()**
    label2.pack()
    label3.pack(pady=20)
    labelimg2.image = img8
    labelimg2.pack()
    label4.pack()
    temp.close()
```

Comment: Not exactly a minimal example. Also: try writing out the code manually - grab the json ouput, extract the icon, try writing the Python code to show it. You're probably not just new to Python, breaking down a problem in manageable chunks is an elementary skill.

Comment: Sorry, don´t understand, how do i extract the icon?, i write all the code. thanky you

Comment: That's what I'm trying to point out: break up a problem in smaller and smaller bits until you can handle them.

Comment: ok, the code is ok, my only problem is to show the forecast icon when i run the program, only put some part off the code to understand.

Answer (score 0):

`parsed_json["current_observation"]["icon_url"]` will returns the current weather icon of the location.

More specific:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import json
>>> url = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/<Your API key>/geolookup/conditions/q/<Your location>.json"
>>> temp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
>>> json_string = temp.read().decode('utf-8')
>>> parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
>>> parsed_json["current_observation"]["icon_url"]
'http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif'
```

Comment: thank you, but the problem is the icon don´t appear when i run the code

Comment: i put your code in my, but the problem is the same, the forecast icon don´t appear, when i put the icon in a label don´t show nothing